# PHP if a = 1 or 2 then do something

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

I have conditional PHP working fine, the condition is if the url ends with url-1:

```
if ($currentpage == '/url-1') {
```

How can I change this so the url can be either url-1 or url-2? I cant get the syntax right. 
Thanks

Comment: Apparently not much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fella...that was hard to believe....

```
if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || $currentpage == '/url-2') {
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || $currentpage == '/url-2')
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the || (logical OR) operator. More information on [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

You can use it like so:

```
if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || $currentpage == '/url-2') {
```

Be sure not to use:

```
if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || '/url-2') {
```

as this is valid but does not do what you would expect it to do.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried REGEX?

```
$pattern = '/^\/url-[12]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $currentpage, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {

}
```

That way, if you have lots of pages (1,2,...), you don't need a special case for each.

Comment: REGEX is way too much overhead for such a simple operation.

Comment: @George Unless this ends up scaling, that is.

Comment: Agreed... And what will you suggest when he reaches the:
`if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || $currentpage == '/url-2' || $currentpage == '/url-3' || $currentpage == '/url-4' || $currentpage == '/url-5' || $currentpage == '/url-6' || $currentpage == '/url-7' || $currentpage == '/url-8' || $currentpage == '/url-9')` ???

Comment: @tyron `if(in_array($currentpage))` and have an array of accepted values.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || $currentpage == '/url-2') {
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
   if ($currentpage == '/url-1' || $currentpage == '/url-2') {
```